# How to remove by group based on certain NA columns and certain time frame?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, economics

I have the below panel df containing worker layoff and wage information. I want to restrict my df to only those respondents who have **3 consecutive years of earnings before their layoff** (layoff year is indicated by PermSeparation==1)

As I see it, the coding restrictions are --> keep only the PersonIDs who satisfy:

1. Non-missing *consecutive* EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1/2/3/4
2. Time_To_Layoff is between -3 and -1

I tried:

```
test2 <- test %>%
          group_by(PersonID) %>%
          filter(!is.na('EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1'), !is.na('EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr2'),
               !is.na('EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr3'), !is.na('EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4') & Time_To_Layoff %in% -1:-3)
```

When I run the above, I get this error:
*Error in `filter()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.*

I thought I could for sure puzzle this out myself, but something isn't adding up.

Current df:

The highlighted rows indicate the 3 years before a layoff for each respondent where I want non-missing earnings.

So for example, PersonID 1534 would not be dropped because they have a complete series of non-missing earnings for the 3 years before their layoff in 2016.
On the other hand, PersonID 636 would get dropped from the df because they have missing earnings for the 3 years before their layoff in 2014.
[image]

And here are the first 45 rows of the df:

```
structure(list(CalendarYear = c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2003, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), PersonID = c(278, 
278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 278, 278, 278, 278, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 
636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 636, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 
1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534, 1534), LayoffCalendarYear = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 2008, NA, 2010, NA, NA, 2013, NA, NA, 2016, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2014, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2016, NA, NA), 
    LayoffCalendarQuarter = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 4, NA, 
    NA, 3, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), LayoffTimeID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 20080331, NA, 20101231, NA, NA, 20130930, NA, NA, 20160331, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20140930, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20160331, 
    NA, NA), Time_To_Layoff = c(-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, 
    -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, 
    -2, -1, 0, 1, 2), PermSeparation = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    MassLayoffFlag = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), IndividualLayOff = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), County = c(177, 177, 
    177, 177, 177, 177, 179, 123, 177, 177, 177, 53, 177, 177, 
    9, 177, 177, 177, 163, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 141, 53, 
    53, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 103, 147, 147, 147, 147, 
    147, 147, 37, 147, 147), industryID = c(1086, 1086, 1086, 
    1086, 1086, 1086, 1078, 1086, 1086, 1086, 1086, 1084, 1086, 
    1086, 1086, 1086, 1086, 1086, 1086, 852, 852, 852, 852, 852, 
    852, 852, 926, 852, 852, 933, 933, 933, 933, 933, 933, 763, 
    933, 933, 909, 909, 909, 909, 930, 930, 930), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1 = c(15018, 
    13125, 765, 14111, 6838, 4301, 13674, NA, 5475, NA, 11135, 
    NA, NA, 1710, NA, 1076, 1505, NA, 8130, 22115, 12813, 17856, 
    23338, 16250, 15872, 15996, NA, NA, 12946, NA, 20012, 19969, 
    17906, 16849, 25338, 2163, NA, 8211, 3666, 3297, 2931, 7076, 
    12696, 14413, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr2 = c(13445, 
    14486, 5899, 269, 17872, 15704, 10477, 2723, NA, 317, 21157, 
    3356, 342, 1409, 5246, 8008, NA, 401, NA, 16488, 18739, 20200, 
    17769, 15322, 14638, 14045, NA, NA, 17337, NA, 17774, 16266, 
    16173, 14200, NA, 2174, NA, 8726, 6554, 2324, 3697, 6311, 
    11764, 13360, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr3 = c(14663, 
    14557, 15616, 6283, 520, 16766, NA, 19605, 5784, 21487, 20961, 
    NA, 684, 804, 17231, 1740, 383, 1204, NA, 14981, 18706, 23152, 
    19728, 16680, 17457, 17082, NA, 11004, 14392, 19870, 19684, 
    18790, 18463, 18290, NA, 1025, 7210, 6461, 5858, 2426, 6301, 
    6903, 12340, 16158, 13736), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4 = c(13549, 
    10396, 19659, 17556, NA, 7145, NA, 5601, 9341, 1119, NA, 
    21462, 7429, 2466, 11703, 1199, 1532, 2421, NA, 16866, 20898, 
    19682, 16284, 13736, 14440, NA, 7031, 15103, 16969, NA, 17157, 
    16741, 16148, 19480, NA, NA, 8268, NA, 3587, 2920, 5493, 
    5126, 6925, 12160, 15550), OwnershipCode_Qtr1 = c(50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, NA, 50, NA, NA, 50, NA, 50, 50, 
    NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, NA, 50, NA, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyHoursWorked_Qtr1 = c(486, 
    418, 24, 393, 193, 124, 401, NA, 140, NA, 269, NA, NA, 40, 
    NA, 24, 32, NA, 162, 517, 534, 521, 607, 14, 14, 609, NA, 
    NA, 125, NA, 145, 145, 145, 145, 520, 211, NA, 327, 168, 
    149, 130, 264, 331, 367, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1 = c(15018, 
    13125, 765, 14111, 6838, 4301, 13674, NA, 5475, NA, 11135, 
    NA, NA, 1710, NA, 1076, 1505, NA, 8130, 22115, 12813, 17856, 
    23338, 16250, 15872, 15996, NA, NA, 12946, NA, 20012, 19969, 
    17906, 16849, 25338, 2163, NA, 8211, 3666, 3297, 2931, 7076, 
    12696, 14413, NA), EmployeeTenure_Qtr1 = c(3, 7, 11, 2, 4, 
    1, 2, NA, 1, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, 5, NA, 1, 5, 9, 13, 
    17, 21, 25, 29, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 7, 13, 17, 21, 4, NA, 2, 
    3, 7, 11, 15, 1, 2, NA), EmployerLocationTotalWagesPaid_Qtr1 = c(4376588, 
    5558459, 6463352, 6527722, 7827218, 8253747, 6188140, NA, 
    5070204, NA, 7478589, NA, NA, 13707751, NA, 1943390, 2072976, 
    NA, 5644314, 404837, 405388, 482224, 632307, 1003511, 775108, 
    359800, NA, NA, 313275, NA, 173963, 126200, 79439, 101462, 
    111767, 1734, NA, 927103, 9155355, 11392187, 12082773, 12082858, 
    24185966, 6725265, NA), QuarterlyAverageEmployment_Qtr1 = c(277, 
    345, 397, 364, 334, 409, 167, NA, 195, NA, 312, NA, NA, 393, 
    NA, 98, 91, NA, 147, 46, 69, 90, 137, 168, 154, 58, NA, NA, 
    53, NA, 8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 1, NA, 165, 416, 542, 526, 477, 1624, 
    374, NA), OwnershipCode_Qtr2 = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, NA, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, NA, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 
    NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyHoursWorked_Qtr2 = c(434, 
    457, 185, 8, 506, 434, 303, 70, NA, 8, 484, 80, 8, 32, 117, 
    169, NA, 8, NA, 520, 640, 609, 544, 12, 14, 12, NA, NA, 149, 
    NA, 127, 127, 127, 127, NA, 212, NA, 345, 295, 103, 138, 
    229, 289, 353, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr2 = c(13445, 
    14486, 5899, 269, 17872, 15704, 10477, 2723, NA, 317, 21157, 
    3356, 342, 1409, 5246, 8008, NA, 401, NA, 16488, 18739, 20200, 
    17769, 15322, 14638, 14045, NA, NA, 17337, NA, 17774, 16266, 
    16173, 14200, NA, 2174, NA, 8726, 6554, 2324, 3697, 6311, 
    11764, 13360, NA), EmployeeTenure_Qtr2 = c(4, 8, 12, 1, 5, 
    2, 3, 1, NA, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, NA, 1, NA, 6, 10, 14, 18, 
    22, 26, 30, NA, NA, 4, NA, 4, 8, 14, 18, NA, 5, NA, 3, 4, 
    8, 12, 16, 2, 3, NA), EmployerLocationTotalWagesPaid_Qtr2 = c(4973009, 
    6501789, 6531662, 4508191, 7876558, 7305309, 6336353, 3486494, 
    NA, 5471015, 17116358, 15516511, 11592681, 12472180, 2293399, 
    2025045, NA, 2464048, NA, 367174, 483507, 603677, 752983, 
    1100656, 763058, 362176, NA, NA, 339512, NA, 129741, 89566, 
    85289, 88268, NA, 1949, NA, 1089508, 8844702, 12915214, 12343315, 
    9871327, 20808439, 5618925, NA), QuarterlyAverageEmployment_Qtr2 = c(287, 
    362, 372, 213, 344, 385, 192, 174, NA, 236, 492, 806, 495, 
    439, 130, 93, NA, 99, NA, 47, 89, 107, 114, 129, 151, 54, 
    NA, NA, 60, NA, 7, 5, 5, 5, NA, 1, NA, 174, 418, 438, 515, 
    469, 1617, 382, NA), OwnershipCode_Qtr3 = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
    NA, 50, 30, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), EmployeeQuarterlyHoursWorked_Qtr3 = c(467, 
    455, 477, 174, 15, 435, NA, 475, 131, 489, 472, NA, 16, 17, 
    385, 37, 8, 24, NA, 524, 560, 603, 609, 14, 14, 608, NA, 
    73, 118, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, NA, 700, 314, 279, 264, 
    107, 238, 251, 302, 450, 397), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr3 = c(14663, 
    14557, 15616, 6283, 520, 16766, NA, 19605, 5784, 21487, 20961, 
    NA, 684, 804, 17231, 1740, 383, 1204, NA, 14981, 18706, 23152, 
    19728, 16680, 17457, 17082, NA, 11004, 14392, 19870, 19684, 
    18790, 18463, 18290, NA, 1025, 7210, 6461, 5858, 2426, 6301, 
    6903, 12340, 16158, 13736), EmployeeTenure_Qtr3 = c(5, 9, 
    1, 2, 6, 3, NA, 2, 1, 2, 6, NA, 2, 6, 2, 3, 1, 2, NA, 7, 
    11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, NA, 1, 5, 3, 5, 11, 15, 19, NA, 6, 
    1, 4, 5, 9, 13, 17, 3, 4, 1), EmployerLocationTotalWagesPaid_Qtr3 = c(4908572, 
    5338866, 927399, 4451896, 9746087, 7631926, NA, 4433520, 
    5049863, 7699046, 10643057, NA, 17886321, 8584048, 2446268, 
    7350852, 2759886, 2797068, NA, 435628, 470361, 643822, 1035228, 
    1204524, 808669, 487927, NA, 348051, 350997, 162114, 142409, 
    104603, 88172, 94370, NA, 1949, 964890, 1115224, 7587133, 
    10845487, 12328106, 11529583, 24842917, 6301950, 6305531), 
    QuarterlyAverageEmployment_Qtr3 = c(311, 333, 57, 241, 448, 
    407, NA, 212, 225, 312, 396, NA, 569, 361, 134, 305, 118, 
    102, NA, 38, 89, 122, 135, 173, 139, 71, NA, 55, 54, 9, 7, 
    5, 4, 4, NA, 1, 146, 172, 421, 544, 485, 466, 1661, 387, 
    391), OwnershipCode_Qtr4 = c(50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, NA, 
    50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, NA, NA, 50, 
    NA, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), EmployeeQuarterlyHoursWorked_Qtr4 = c(431, 
    326, 539, 485, NA, 168, NA, 137, 237, 28, NA, 509, 171, 56, 
    261, 25, 32, 46, NA, 604, 605, 522, 518, 12, 12, NA, 320, 
    149, 147, NA, 125, 125, 125, 142, NA, NA, 347, NA, 159, 131, 
    206, 186, 171, 372, 399), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4 = c(13549, 
    10396, 19659, 17556, NA, 7145, NA, 5601, 9341, 1119, NA, 
    21462, 7429, 2466, 11703, 1199, 1532, 2421, NA, 16866, 20898, 
    19682, 16284, 13736, 14440, NA, 7031, 15103, 16969, NA, 17157, 
    16741, 16148, 19480, NA, NA, 8268, NA, 3587, 2920, 5493, 
    5126, 6925, 12160, 15550), EmployeeTenure_Qtr4 = c(6, 10, 
    2, 3, NA, 2, NA, 3, 2, 3, NA, 1, 3, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, NA, 8, 
    12, 16, 20, 24, 28, NA, 1, 2, 2, NA, 6, 12, 16, 20, NA, NA, 
    2, NA, 6, 10, 14, 18, 4, 5, 2), EmployerLocationTotalWagesPaid_Qtr4 = c(5532362, 
    5871533, 6298451, 8170601, NA, 5704992, NA, 3145261, 4800055, 
    8196639, NA, 21981416, 18956026, 7713089, 1519066, 2350844, 
    2997932, 2490561, NA, 398778, 444330, 504547, 1043201, 833779, 
    555474, NA, 5930182, 278577, 417996, NA, 111134, 103111, 
    76489, 96781, NA, NA, 1190514, NA, 9847418, 12459033, 10993349, 
    10002876, 21379229, 5508546, 5538134), QuarterlyAverageEmployment_Qtr4 = c(346, 
    362, 368, 439, NA, 186, NA, 152, 233, 271, NA, 864, 574, 
    339, 85, 96, 119, 104, NA, 28, 87, 90, 186, 157, 89, NA, 
    756, 68, 81, NA, 6, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, 161, NA, 425, 537, 491, 
    475, 1678, 385, 379), CountyName.x = c("City of St. Paul", 
    "City of St. Paul", "City of St. Paul", "City of St. Paul", 
    "City of St. Paul", "City of St. Paul", "City of Duluth", 
    "Ramsey County", "City of St. Paul", "City of St. Paul", 
    "City of St. Paul", "Hennepin County", "City of St. Paul", 
    "City of St. Paul", "Benton County", "City of St. Paul", 
    "City of St. Paul", "City of St. Paul", "Washington County", 
    "Hennepin County", "Hennepin County", "Hennepin County", 
    "Hennepin County", "Hennepin County", "Hennepin County", 
    "Hennepin County", "Sherburne County", "Hennepin County", 
    "Hennepin County", "Ramsey County", "Ramsey County", "Ramsey County", 
    "Ramsey County", "Ramsey County", "Ramsey County", "Nicollet County", 
    "Steele County", "Steele County", "Steele County", "Steele County", 
    "Steele County", "Steele County", "Dakota County", "Steele County", 
    "Steele County"), IndustryGroup = c("Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Foundation/Exterior Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Building Equipment Contractors", "Building Equipment Contractors", 
    "Employment Services", "Employment Services", "Employment Services", 
    "Employment Services", "Employment Services", "Employment Services", 
    "Employment Services", "Home Health Care Services", "Employment Services", 
    "Employment Services", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Agencies, Brokerages, and Other Insurance Related Activities", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Offices of Physicians", "Offices of Physicians", "Offices of Physicians", 
    "Offices of Physicians", "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals", 
    "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals", "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals"
    ), industry = c("Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Roofing Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Electrical Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", "Plumbing and HVAC Contractors", 
    "Temporary Help Services", "Temporary Help Services", "Temporary Help Services", 
    "Temporary Help Services", "Temporary Help Services", "Temporary Help Services", 
    "Temporary Help Services", "Home Health Care Services", "Temporary Help Services", 
    "Temporary Help Services", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Insurance Agencies and Brokerages", 
    "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", "Nursing Care Facilities (Skilled Nursing Facilities)", 
    "Offices of Physicians", "Offices of Physicians", "Offices of Physicians", 
    "Offices of Physicians", "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals", 
    "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals", "General Medical and Surgical Hospitals"
    ), sector = c("Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Administrative and Support and Waste Management and Remediation Services", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Finance and Insurance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance", 
    "Health Care and Social Assistance", "Health Care and Social Assistance"
    ), SectorCode = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 
    56, 62, 56, 56, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 52, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
    62, 62, 62, 62, 62), SubSector = c("Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Specialty Trade Contractors", "Specialty Trade Contractors", 
    "Administrative and Support Services", "Administrative and Support Services", 
    "Administrative and Support Services", "Administrative and Support Services", 
    "Administrative and Support Services", "Administrative and Support Services", 
    "Administrative and Support Services", "Ambulatory Health Care Services", 
    "Administrative and Support Services", "Administrative and Support Services", 
    "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", 
    "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", 
    "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", 
    "Insurance Carriers and Related Activities", "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", 
    "Nursing and Residential Care Facilities", "Ambulatory Health Care Services", 
    "Ambulatory Health Care Services", "Ambulatory Health Care Services", 
    "Ambulatory Health Care Services", "Hospitals", "Hospitals", 
    "Hospitals"), SubSectorCode = c(238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 
    238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 
    238, 238, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 561, 621, 561, 561, 
    623, 623, 623, 623, 623, 623, 524, 623, 623, 621, 621, 621, 
    621, 622, 622, 622), Sum_Non_NA = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 29, 35, 
    23, 30, 29, 29, 29, 24, 29, 35, 30, 35, 29, 29, 18, 36, 36, 
    36, 36, 36, 36, 30, 18, 24, 36, 18, 36, 36, 36, 36, 18, 30, 
    24, 30, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 24), BirthMonthYear = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "XX-5-1967", NA, "XX-5-1967", NA, NA, "XX-5-1967", 
    NA, NA, "XX-5-1967", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "XX-7-1967", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "XX-1-1969", NA, NA), BirthYear = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "1967", NA, "1967", NA, NA, "1967", NA, NA, 
    "1967", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "1967", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "1969", NA, NA), AGEatLayoff = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    41, NA, 43, NA, NA, 46, NA, NA, 49, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47, NA, NA), Gender = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "M", NA, "M", NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, "M", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "F", NA, 
    NA), GroupCode = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2382, NA, 2382, NA, 
    NA, 2382, NA, NA, 2382, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5613, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6211, NA, NA), DegreeLevel1 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DegreeLevel2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    DegreeSeeking = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DisablingCondition = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), EnrollmentStatus = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), IPEDSZip.y = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "55912-1473", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), cpi = c(184, 188.908333333333, 195.266666666667, 
    201.558333333333, 207.344166666667, 215.25425, 214.564666666667, 
    218.076166666667, 224.923, 229.586083333333, 232.95175, 236.715, 
    237.00175, 240.005416666667, 245.121, 251.098916666667, 255.6465, 
    258.83825, 270.965416666667, 184, 188.908333333333, 195.266666666667, 
    201.558333333333, 207.344166666667, 215.25425, 214.564666666667, 
    229.586083333333, 232.95175, 236.715, 240.005416666667, 245.121, 
    251.098916666667, 255.6465, 258.83825, 270.965416666667, 
    184, 218.076166666667, 224.923, 229.586083333333, 232.95175, 
    236.715, 237.00175, 240.005416666667, 245.121, 251.098916666667
    ), adj_factor = c(0.679053446242371, 0.697167688988601, 0.72063316813185, 
    0.743852613417764, 0.765205276811155, 0.794397501526179, 
    0.791852588814378, 0.804811807164813, 0.830080099397678, 
    0.84728924509124, 0.859710264378757, 0.87359856808295, 0.874656821211809, 
    0.885741876654001, 0.904620977154219, 0.926682525599054, 
    0.943465417634784, 0.95524459609698, 1, 0.679053446242371, 
    0.697167688988601, 0.72063316813185, 0.743852613417764, 0.765205276811155, 
    0.794397501526179, 0.791852588814378, 0.84728924509124, 0.859710264378757, 
    0.87359856808295, 0.885741876654001, 0.904620977154219, 0.926682525599054, 
    0.943465417634784, 0.95524459609698, 1, 0.679053446242371, 
    0.804811807164813, 0.830080099397678, 0.84728924509124, 0.859710264378757, 
    0.87359856808295, 0.874656821211809, 0.885741876654001, 0.904620977154219, 
    0.926682525599054), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1_adj = c(22116.0794972826, 
    18826.1736843266, 1061.5664582622, 18970.1558419812, 8936.1641996198, 
    5414.16607144032, 17268.3655937449, NA, 6595.74901744153, 
    NA, 12952.0379846184, NA, NA, 1930.58502151861, NA, 1161.13120758851, 
    1595.18300498279, NA, 8130, 32567.392334692, 18378.6486413163, 
    24778.2100375555, 31374.4948650101, 21236.1316530889, 19979.9218521043, 
    20200.729562494, NA, NA, 14819.163484218, NA, 22121.9720804555, 
    21548.9117884154, 18978.9680313767, 17638.4143588387, 25338, 
    3185.31628396739, NA, 9891.81647163696, 4326.73968333592, 
    3835.01295332617, 3355.0879169043, 8090.03008768219, 14333.7470369592, 
    15932.6395960226, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr2_adj = c(19799.6197124094, 
    20778.3582469452, 8185.85691148856, 361.630778930831, 23355.8243017849, 
    19768.4408244359, 13230.9979761346, 3383.39966655381, NA, 
    374.134337047868, 24609.453762063, 3841.58138830802, 391.010498867624, 
    1590.75689784779, 5799.11380841842, 8641.57872710854, NA, 
    419.787771256116, NA, 24280.8575543478, 26878.7557082359, 
    28030.9051724138, 23887.7966945053, 20023.3851808386, 18426.543351254, 
    17736.887140862, NA, NA, 19845.4995617092, NA, 19648.0077832309, 
    17552.9370098836, 17142.1227505559, 14865.3026230345, NA, 
    3201.51530344203, NA, 10512.2385253324, 7735.25692432722, 
    2703.23630680316, 4231.92085595195, 7215.40134021514, 13281.5217503772, 
    14768.6161800362, NA), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr3_adj = c(21593.292959692, 
    20880.1988817328, 21669.8324342779, 8446.56573986025, 679.556212898844, 
    21105.3030350543, NA, 24359.7320832859, 6968.00224965878, 
    25359.6987386358, 24381.4699771519, NA, 782.020997735249, 
    907.71365924033, 19047.7563920812, 1877.66570743867, 405.950226517216, 
    1260.41016606574, NA, 22061.5918863225, 26831.4213286867, 
    32127.3027995903, 26521.3829247116, 21798.0723676014, 21975.1446429048, 
    21572.1969483947, NA, 12799.6610671523, 16474.3859775116, 
    22433.1721506285, 21759.3892880115, 20276.6314038923, 19569.3447315597, 
    19146.9285193874, NA, 1509.45408740942, 8958.61608367719, 
    7783.58619208944, 6913.81371112433, 2821.88092956302, 7212.69497250562, 
    7892.23822714389, 13931.824073415, 17861.6242692385, 14822.7679065388
    ), EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4_adj = c(19952.7740783515, 
    14911.7639331245, 27280.1764744793, 23601.4496465043, NA, 
    8994.23775411325, NA, 6959.39094100915, 11253.1308807162, 
    1320.68240743396, NA, 24567.3479606278, 8493.61694762451, 
    2784.10682050579, 12936.9098169883, 1293.86274897642, 1623.80090606886, 
    2534.42941199765, NA, 24837.5147690217, 29975.5716308615, 
    27312.0928516558, 21891.4334725266, 17950.7387314972, 18177.297854359, 
    NA, 8298.22878165162, 17567.5464464923, 19424.2534499997, 
    NA, 18965.9541767127, 18065.5181656499, 17115.6246939948, 
    20392.6827532896, NA, NA, 10273.2091234179, NA, 4233.50115769938, 
    3396.49312214511, 6287.78503157806, 5860.58426080539, 7818.30483860607, 
    13442.0937686557, 16780.2883624548), EmployeeAnnualWages_adj = c(20865.4415619339, 
    18849.1236865323, 14549.358069627, 12844.9505018192, NA, 
    13820.5369212609, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1803.29059977813, 
    NA, 3243.55959777803, NA, NA, NA, 25936.839136096, 25516.0993272751, 
    28062.1277153038, 25918.7769891884, 20252.0819832565, 19639.7269251556, 
    NA, NA, NA, 17640.8256183596, NA, 20623.8308321026, 19360.9995919603, 
    18201.5150518718, 18010.8320636376, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5802.32786912171, 
    3189.15582795937, 5271.87219423498, 7264.56347896165, 12341.3494248394, 
    15501.2434534883, NA)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), groups = structure(list(
    PersonID = c(278, 636, 1534), .rows = structure(list(1:19, 
        20:35, 36:45), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unorthodox, but essentially I'm filtering based on the ID pulled from the values obtained when I `slice` for the 3 years before permanent separation and look for `anyNA` values within that subset

```
filter(df |> tibble::repair_names(), PersonID %in% (df |> 
         tibble::repair_names() |> 
         group_by(PersonID) |> 
         slice((which(PermSeparation == 1) - 3):which(PermSeparation == 1)) |> 
         filter(!anyNA(c_across(EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1:EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4))) |> 
         pull(PersonID)))
```

```
CalendarYear PersonID LayoffCalendarYear LayoffCalendarQuarter LayoffTimeID Time_To_Layoff PermSeparation MassLayoffFlag
          <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>                 <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
 1         2003     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -7              0             NA
 2         2010     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -6              0             NA
 3         2011     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -5              0             NA
 4         2012     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -4              0             NA
 5         2013     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -3              0             NA
 6         2014     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -2              0             NA
 7         2015     1534                 NA                    NA           NA             -1              0             NA
 8         2016     1534               2016                     1     20160331              0              1              1
 9         2017     1534                 NA                    NA           NA              1              0             NA
10         2018     1534                 NA                    NA           NA              2              0             NA
```

Edit:

filter seems to run slow. Not quite sure why, maybe someone with greater knowledge can inform us on that.

a base R replacement is

```
subset(df, PersonID %in% (df |> 
tibble::repair_names() |> 
group_by(PersonID) |> 
slice((which(PermSeparation == 1) - 3):which(PermSeparation == 1)) |> 
filter(!anyNA(c_across(EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr1:EmployeeQuarterlyWages_Qtr4))) |> 
pull(PersonID)))
```

Comment: I tried the base R code and it looks good. Thanks Jahi!

Comment: No problem. If the issue is solved, hit the check mark within my post to resolve this question.